# create multiple sheets as pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have this section of code that asks for a folder to save PDFs to. If you cancel or close the application, the path of the file is still selected. I want to select the file from the path only if you don't select a folder, and I don't want any action to be taken if you press cancel or close the application.

````
Dim folder_path as string
Dim sh as worksheet
Dim filename as string

with application.filedialog(msofiledialogfolderpicker)
  .title = "Select the folder path"
  if .show = -1 then
  Folder_path = .selectedItems(1)
  else
  Folder_path = Thisworkbook.path
  end if
end with```
````

Comment: You need to remove the `Else` clause of your `If` statement

Comment: This works for the cancel button and closing the application, but if you do not select a folder and click OK, the path of the file is not picked up.

Comment: If you want your file's path to be the default then add `.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path` somewhere before the `If` statement.

Comment: Another option (which is ugly - sorry) is to add this line `.InitialFileName = "select a folder"`. As this is not a valid folder path, pressing OK without changing the folder will not be accepted.

Comment: Can you better explain what does "I want to select the file from the path only if you don't select a folder" mean?

Comment: When the code asks you “select the folder path” and you do not make a selection and just press ok to save the pdfs to the file’s path.